# Threading with Tkinter bind and canvas

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, bind

I am having problems with Tkinter's `canvas.coords()` method. I am trying to update the canvas every 1/60 of a second and trying to detect when the Right arrow key is pressed. The problem is that when I keep the right arrow pressed for a while I get an error :

http://postimage.org/image/bdfk3m8gx/

My script is 'novo.py' and the code is given below. Any help perhaps? I'm just a begginer.

```
import Tkinter, threading, time

def real_time(td, canvas):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1/60.0)
        canvas.coords('line',1,1,200,200)

def func(event):
    print 'key pressed'


root = Tkinter.Tk()
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(1,1,100,100, tag='line')
root.bind('<Right>', func)
thread = threading.Thread(target = real_time, args = (1/60.0, canvas))
thread.start()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What versions of Python, Tkinter, and Tk are you using ? But, more important, GUI packages commonly behaves wrongly when you change its elements in a different thread than the one you started it. You either simplified your problem too much, or you don't need thread at all for this. Take a look into the method `after` available in Tkinter.

Comment: i use python 2.7.3 and everything that is installed with it. i would like to use after but the problem with it is that you cannot pass any argument cause stack gets too big than because it is called recursively

Comment: Tkinter is not thread-safe. This might help: http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/mtTkinter   Not sure what you are trying to achieve, though. Instead of updating all the time you should probably use some event binding.

Comment: i'm sorry. after method is perfect. i obviously used it in wrong way, this example runs without any problems. thanks mmgp :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter is not thread safe, and quite often threads simply aren't needed.

In your case you can use `after` to periodically ron something every N milliseconds. For example, to run something approximately 60 times per second you would do something like this:

```
def real_time():
    <do something here>
    self.after(16, real_time)
```

Then, call this function once when your program starts up:

```
real_time()
```