# Tkinter 'bind' with 'canvas' and threading ValueError

Tags: python, multithreading, canvas, tkinter

At first, I thought this was an issue that could be solved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004888/threading-with-tkinter-bind-and-canvas) post that I found. However, I have tried to implement the after method but it seems to not work. (More info on how I believe my question is different and *not* a duplicate is a little further down below.)

The error is formed when trying to bind `button-1` to the function `callback`, which is running from a different thread than everything else. The code in question is here

```
def callback(event):
    print(event)  #This function normally changes playerY, however it prints the event for debugging purpose.

def drawPlayer():
    global playerY, playerY2
    player = canvas.create_oval(50,50,100,100,fill="yellow",outline="black")
    while True:
        canvas.coords(player,(50,50,100,100))  #This would usually use playerY and playerY2 but for debugging it does not.
        playerY += 0.0018
        playerY2 += 0.0018

root.bind("<Button-1>",callback)
thread2 = Thread(target=drawPlayer)
thread2.start()
```

Obviously things such as root, playerY, playerY2 etc are already definded but I am not going to paste my whole code.

When button 1 is clicked this will produce the following traceback

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 594, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Harvey\Documents\School Work\Computer    Science\Tkinter\tkinterFallpyBird.py", line 58, in drawPlayer
    canvas.coords(player,(50,50,100,100))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in coords
     self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2297, in <listcomp>
    return [getdouble(x) for x in
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'None'
```

The other thread tells me to solve this by using the 'after' method. To do this I tried:

```
def drawPlayer():
    global playerY, playerY2,player
    canvas.coords(player,(playerY,50,playerY2,100))
    playerY += 0.0018
    playerY2 += 0.0018

    root.after(1,drawPlayer)

root.bind("<Button-1>",callback)

player = canvas.create_oval(50,50,100,100,fill="yellow",outline="black")
drawPlayer()

root.mainloop()
```

My function `drawPlayer` needs to be called repeatedly, hence the while loop in the threaded version. I feel this is how my question differs from the one I linked at the start. I tried to use `0` in the `root.after()` call, but that just leads to code after the call of `drawPlayer()` not being run.

Unless, I am missing something to do with the `after` method, or the threading module, I don't understand how I can fix this issue.

---

Side note: I realise I should not be making a game in tkinter, especially one that requires multiple things to be happening at once. However, I am doing this at school and the modules I would like to use (Pygame or Pyglet) cannot be downloaded just for me to make a game that has no real purpose. If I could use something other than tkinter I probably would. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What result did you get in version with `after()` ? Did you try `after()` with bigger value ? For example `10` ? With `1` (one milisecond) you could get 1000 FPS (frames per second) but you don't need it.

Comment: @furas I tried it will 10, 20, 50, and 100. None of these did anything. The function was being called, but the coords were not changing even after I changed then to use playerY and playerY2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `after` version but add something more then `0.0018` to `playerY` and  `playerY2`.

Try at least `1`

Working example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

playerY = 50
playerY2 = 100

def drawPlayer():
    global playerY, playerY2,player
    canvas.coords(player,(playerY,50,playerY2,100))
    playerY += 1
    playerY2 += 1
    root.after(10,drawPlayer)

#root.bind("<Button-1>",callback)

player = canvas.create_oval(50,50,100,100,fill="yellow",outline="black")
drawPlayer()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly I can't try this just yet, but this won't work for my needs. The reason the value was so small is because I need to oval to slowly fall down at a reasonable speed. If it is at 1, it will fall off the screen too quickly.

Comment: Then use bigger value in `after()`. For example changing `10` to `100` you get 10 times slower move. It give you the same result as adding `0.1` in place of `1` but you will use less CPU power and it will work in the same speed on every computer - using `after()` animation speed depends on time, not CPU speed. And you can easly add another `after()` to make another animated element.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I assume this will work, although I won't be able to try it until later tomorrow night!