# Tkinter Scrolling Canvas Widget speed issues

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am currently remaking flappy bird in Tkinter. (I understand this is bad, I explain why at the bottom.) My issue is with the pipes, and the speeds they scroll at and the distance they are from each other. Unless something is wrong with my logic, if a start the two pipes separated from each other then move them when they get to a certain point, and place them at the same point, they should retain the gap between them. This may be better explained in code.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry('430x640')
root.configure(background='turquoise')
canvas = Canvas(root,width=int(435),height=int(645))
canvas.configure(background='turquoise')
canvas.pack()


x, x2 = 400, 700

y = random.randint(0,300)
y2 = random.randint(0,300)

def drawPipe():
    global x,x2,y,y2

    canvas.coords(pipeTop,(x,0,(x+50),y))
    canvas.coords(pipeBottom,(x,640,(x+50),(y+150)))


    canvas.coords(pipeTop2,(x2,0,(x2+50),y2))
    canvas.coords(pipeBottom2,(x2,640,(x2+50),(y2+150)))

    x -= 3
    x2 -= 3
    if x < -46:
        x = 435
        y = random.randint(5,540)


    if x2 <-46:
        x2 = 435
        y2 = random.randint(5,540)

    root.after(1,drawPipe)

pipeTop = canvas.create_rectangle(x,0,(x+50),y,fill='green')
pipeBottom = canvas.create_rectangle(x,640,x+50,y+150,fill='green')

pipeTop2 = canvas.create_rectangle(x2,0,(x2+50),y,fill='green')
pipeBottom2 = canvas.create_rectangle(x2,640,(x2+50),(y2+150),fill='green')
drawPipe()

root.mainloop()
```

This is not my full code, but it is the bit concerned with drawing and updating the pipes. When run, this code will show you how the pipes scrolling speed up and down. I do not understand how this is possible. All the values for the pipes are the same apart from the starting positions. Is this due to the inefficient way Tkinter uses the `after` method? I attempted to use threading but this produced problems when using `root.bind` (see my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561115/tkinter-bind-with-canvas-and-threading-valueerror) question). Or is it due to a logic error? Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me.

---

Side note: I realise I should not be making a game in tkinter, especially one that requires multiple things to be happening at once. However, I am doing this at school and the modules I would like to use (Pygame or Pyglet) cannot be downloaded just for me to make a game that has no real purpose. If I could use something other than tkinter I probably would. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using `after(1,..)` you get 1000FPS (Frames Per Second) but you don't need it - use `after(20, ...)` to get 50 FPS - beside using `after(1,..)` your program have no time to do other things.

Comment: Tkinter is fine for simple games. You should be able to write flappy bird in tkinter without threads, and without performance problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `after(1,..)` you get `1000FPS` (Frames Per Second) but you don't need it - use `after(20, ...)` to get `50 FPS`.

Beside using `after(1,..)` your program have no time to do other things - it have no time to execute all `after()` so you can get different speed.

With `after(1,..)` I couldn't even move window.
And my CPU became hotter so fan started working faster and louder.